# Which subfolders from data folder solr do replicate?

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing

I want to add additional data to solr data folder, not sure how to force solr to replicate it. Seems like by default solr only replicate index/spellcheck folders.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the index the [Configuration files in the conf file are also replciated](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#How_are_configuration_files_replicated.3F).
You can add files and mention them to be replicated as well.

Comment: Also, according to the 2nd bullet in the link @Jayendra supplied, only files in the conf folder can be replicated. So there are not any built in mechanisms to replicate additional files in the solr data folder.

Comment: yup not in the data folder. But custom files in conf folder can be replicated.